# Ошибка NoClassDefFoundError в командной строке

Tags: java

Пытаюсь использовать свой же jar файл в другом проекте, при работе в Eclipse проблем нет, но если пытаться запустить через командную строку выдаёт ошибку `NoClassDefFoundError`. Библиотека лежит в папке libs.

```
package com.bee.json;

import com.bee.JSONelements.JSONBaseElement;
import com.bee.parseJSON.BaseParser;
import com.bee.workWithFile.ReadFromFile;

public class TestJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     String jsonString = ReadFromFile.readFile("d:/anotherJson.txt");
    System.out.println("Formated from file: " + jsonString);
    JSONBaseElement parserJson = BaseParser.mainParse(jsonString);
    System.out.println(parserJson);
  }
}
```

Это выполняю в командной строке

```
javac -sourcepath ./src -cp ./libs/* -d classFoulder src\com\bee\json\TestJSON.java
java -cp .;../libs/*;D:\workspace\TestJSON\classFoulder com.bee.json.TestJSON
```

Компилирует без ошибок, но во время выполнения команды java пишет ошибку `NoClassDefFoundError` (как я понимаю не может его найти). Однако в том же Eclipse всё нормально запускается и работает. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: А почему пути для `javac` и `java` так отличаются (`../libs` вместо `./libs`, полный путь вместо `classFoulder`)? В `classFoulder` создается файл `\com\bee\json\TestJSON.class`?

Comment: Спасибо, заработало) почему-то сам не обратил на это внимание